# Is a thread holding the respective mutex on a spurious wakeup?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, synchronization, pthreads

Let's take a look at the code below. 
Suppose a thread sees *ready*=false and therefore waits on the condition variable *mv_cv*, hence releasing the mutex *my_mutex* and putting itself to sleep.
Some time later, something spuriously wakes the thread up while *ready* still holds the value false. My question is:
Is the thread now holding the mutex *my_mutex* by reacquiring the mutex before waking up?

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&my_mutex);

while ( !ready )
{
        pthread_cond_wait(&my_cv, &my_mutex);
}

//some operation goes here

pthread_mutex_unlock(&my_mutex);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Spurious wake-up is one kind of successful return, and post condition (reacquiring lock of the mutex) will be fulfilled.

Comment: Heh 'Spurious wake-up is one kind of successful return'.  I understand what you're saying, but it still sounds like a warning in a file system doc: "NOTE - may occasionally open the wrong file'.